# 2007 Subaru Legacy not engaging any gears

Tags: transmission, clutch, subaru, legacy

I was driving home the other night and I felt something snap below me. Immediately after, I had no acceleration. I can move the shift into any gear, but it's as if the car is staying in neutral. It also won't stall.

I got the clutch kit replaced a few months ago (which I'm starting to regret).

Any thoughts on what might have happened?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! The first place I'd look is at the shifter linkage. You sure it's *actually* going into gear? Or is it the shifter is moving without it engaging?

Answer (score 1):

This depends on a few things.

If this happened while you were moving, and you suddenly lost acceleration I would think of the following things.

- Driveshaft/Propshaft
- Clutch (Just been replaced so this is probably fine)

If it happened while you were shifting gear, it is probably the shift linkages.
When you shift, if it does not click into gear, or you feel no resistance shifting gears then it is likely this.

If you were accelerating/launching hard or doing other things that would stress the vehicle, it is probably the driveshaft or another driveline component.